# Passing multiple parameters to python script through a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have the following code in my batch file

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P NAME=Enter name:
SET /P GENDER = Enter age:
SET /P AGE = Enter gender:
python test.py %NAME% %GENDER% %AGE%
PAUSE
```

Here is the code in test.py

```
import sys

print len(sys.argv)

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

Here is the output

```
Enter name:Dodo
Enter age:1
Enter DB gender:M
2
test.py
Dodo
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am using python2.5.
How do i pass the age and gender as well? I'm new to both python and batch programming, so go easy on me :)

Comment: Why don't you just put the whole program in Python? Have it prompt for input.

Comment: thanks :) will try that out, but can it be done this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not use spaces around the `=` in `set`:

```
SET /P NAME=Enter name:
SET /P GENDER=Enter age:
SET /P AGE=Enter gender:
```

Otherwise you get a variable that *ends with a space* and you'd have to use it like `%GENDER %`.

Answer (score 1):

try enclosing in quotes. you also have a space by the equal signs, not sure if thats a problem with batch...

spaces:

```
SET /P GENDER = Enter age:
SET /P AGE = Enter gender:
```

and none for:

```
SET /P NAME=Enter name:
```